# C++ expression templates ambiguous operator overloading

Tags: c++, expression-templates

Im trying to implement vector and matrix expression templates.Both have the operator+ overload but i get ambiguous operator error.

How can i overload operators for both matrix and vector while retaining the effects of expression templates?

Here is my matrix sum template:

```
    template<typename E1, typename E2>
class MatSum: public MatExpression<MatSum<E1,E2>>{
    E1 const& _u;
    E2 const& _v;

public:
    MatSum(E1 const &u, E2 const &v): _u(u), _v(v){
        assert(u.height() == v.height() && u.width() == v.width());
    }

    double operator[](size_t i) const {return _u[i] + _v[i]; }

    size_t size() const {return _u.size();}
    size_t width() const {return _u.width();}
    size_t height() const {return _u.height();}
};

template<typename E1, typename E2>
MatSum<E1,E2> operator+(E1 const& u, E2 const& v){
    return MatSum<E1,E2>(u,v);
}
```

and here is vector sum template:

```
template <typename E1, typename E2>
class VecSum : public VecExpression<VecSum<E1, E2>>{
    E1 const& _u;
    E2 const& _v;

public:
    VecSum(E1 const & u, E2 const &v): _u(u), _v(v){
        assert(u.size() == v.size());
    }

    double operator[](size_t i) const {return _u[i] + _v[i]; }
    size_t size() const {return _v.size(); }
};


template <typename E1, typename E2>
VecSum<E1, E2> operator+(E1 const &u, E2 const &v){
    return VecSum<E1,E2>(u,v);
}
```

And the code piece that causes the error:

```
    Vec v1 = {67.12,34.8,90.34};

    Vec v2 = {34.90,111.9,45.12};

    Vec sum = v1+v2;

Matrix m0 = {{1.0,1.0,1.0},{1.0,1.0,1.0},{1.0,1.0,1.0}};
    Matrix m1 = {{1.0,1.0,1.0},{1.0,1.0,1.0},{1.0,1.0,1.0}};

    Matrix summ = m0 + m0;
```

Comment: Have you tried to define operator+ as member method of your class ?

Comment: If you only have one type of `Vec` and `Matrix` you can make the operator take parameters of that type instead of using templates. Otherwise you can do the same thing using SFINAE, make the `VecSum` operator take only `Vec<...>` parameters.

Comment: `MatSum::operator[]` returns `double` ?

Comment: @Gojita - operator overloading is more of a syntactic sugar for the template constructors. The whole point is to minimize the assembly code that will be generated when program is compiled. I think putting the operator as member of the class will contradict this idea.

Comment: @super - I tryed using SFINAE but failed, SFINAE is kinda difficult to understand how to use it.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yes. The whole setup constructs a expression tree that will then collapse into more concise piece of code that will create the new matrix without creating any intermediary temp variables. Its the point of Expression templates. Matrix class has a constructor that accepts MatExpression as parameter, and only there will the equation be evaluated, no where else.

Comment: I meant that I expect `MatSum::operator[]` to returns some kind of `VecView`, or taking `std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>`.

Answer (score 3):

Templates can not be specialized with return type.

In your case compiler can not choose which `operator+` to call as both of them can be instantinated with any two types.
Consider these example:

```
Vec v1 = {67.12,34.8,90.34};
Matrix m1 = {{1.0,1.0,1.0},{1.0,1.0,1.0},{1.0,1.0,1.0}};
auto sum = v1+m1;
```

Which of the two operators should be called here? It's ambiguous for compiler.

You can make two not template operator+, which have `(Vec, Vec)` and `(Matrix, Matrix)` arguments or use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to check template operator argument types for some condition and substitute needed `operator+` specialization.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to distinguish between your two templates, so it's an ambiguous call. You will have to restrict the one that returns `MatSum` to only apply to matrix-like arguments, and/or the one that returns `VecSum` to only apply to vector-like arguments.

Let's assume you add a member alias `using kind = Mat;` to `MatExpression` and `Matrix`, and `using kind = Vec` to `VecExpression` and `Vector`. We then make a traits class

```
template<typename E1, typename E2, typename = typename E1::kind, typename = typename E2::kind>
struct Traits;

template<typename E1, typename E2>
struct Traits<E1, E2, Mat, Mat>
{
    using sum_type = MatSum<E1, E2>;
    // others, e.g. using prod_type = MatProd<E1, E2>;
};

template<typename E1, typename E2>
struct Traits<E1, E2, Vec, Vec>
{
    using sum_type = VecSum<E1, E2>;
    // others, e.g. using prod_type = VecProd<E1, E2>;
};
```

And some alias templates, e.g.

```
template<typename E1, typename E2>
using sum_t = typename Traits<E1, E2>::sum_type;
```

We can then constrain our `+` overload to only exist when `Traits` exists.

```
template<typename E1, typename E2>
sum_t<E1, E2> operator+(E1 const& u, E2 const& v){
    return sum_t<E1, E2>(u, v);
}
```

Comment: alias is from C++11, You might even directly do `template<typename E1, typename E2, typename = E1::kind, typename = E2::kind>
struct Traits`

Comment: @Jarod42 I get confused on the history because all the `using foo_t = typename foo<>::type` aliases in `std` are C++14

Comment: I based my expression templates on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates sins Vec is a subclass of VecExpression. Then it should suffice if the using kind = Vec only for VecExpression. correct?

Comment: @Caleth im trying to add this Traits class. But i fail atthe point of using kind = Mat; and using kind = Vec;. Do i have to create some empty classes for Mat and Vec and then i can use this? Or how do you do that?

Comment: @MarkoTaht It can be any two distinct types

Comment: @Caleth but where should the using kind = Mat; be? How would one actually use it? And can i place this traits stuff in a separate header file or should it all be in one place?

Comment: @MarkoTaht as a member of `Matrix` and also as a member of `MatExpression`

Comment: @Caleth traits.h|7|error: need 'typename' before 'E1::kind' because 'E1' is a dependent scope|

Comment: @MarkoTaht: So add `typename` as compiler tells you :-) (`typename E1::kind`).

Comment: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)|

Comment: @MarkoTaht I'm not sure what template you are recursively instantiating there

Comment: @Caleth this error seems to be cause by "template<typename E1, typename E2>
using sum_t = typename Traits<E1,E2>::sum_type;"

Comment: @MarkoTaht yes, but there's no loop of definitions up to `MatExpression<MatSum<Mat,Mat>>` in the code shown. If you remove all the vector code, and the traits, does `MatExpression<MatSum<Mat,Mat>>` still have infinite descent of template expansion?

Comment: @Caleh I placed the full code i currently have here https://codeshare.io/5wxbQj And pure Matrix code works just fine.

Comment: @Caleth Pure Matrix ET or pure Vector ET works just fine. Its the step where i want both of them in the same program i start getting the abiguiti problem. And the infinte decent comes when i add in the changes to doe the sum_t thing.

Comment: Aah... found the issue... problem was that using kind was set as private :D